# Live control of rewired application parameter using MIDI controller in Ableton

Tags: midi, ableton, automation, reason

I am running Reason rewired through Ableton Live. I would like to be able to control one of the parameters of a Subtractor Synthesiser within Reason whilst rewire is active. The actual parameter is a LFO rate.

Currently, the best solution I have come across is to create a different clip for each LFO oscillation rate and set a different envelope automation level to each clip (the clips contain no notes). In this case, I assign a different MIDI trigger to each of the LFO rates I'd like to use live.

However, this is a little cumbersome. First of all, I'd like to avoid having to actually *launch* my Ableton set, since in my experience, this is when things are most likely to crash (I'm using Ableton in Windows with a bunch of VSTs, and believe me, this is a recipe for disaster on stage if I hit the play button). Secondly, in order to control the LFOs by this method I need several trigger buttons free; ideally I'd be able to use a rotary and adjust it on-the-fly.

Any ideas how I can access the parameter? I know that the 'LFO rate' from Reason is mapped to MIDI CC #26, but I can't seem to control this through direct CC assignment from my MIDI controller either; presumably Ableton hijacks MIDI ports when it is open, so I need to have something that involves Ableton.

Comment: Are you trying to control it with a MIDI device? You have to send the midi signal back to Reason through Ableton.

Comment: Yes, I am using a MIDI device (see question title). I know that I need to send the signal to Reason, my question is *how* do I do this whilst rewire is active...

Comment: Can you use a MIDI Loopback port, send the outputed signal to the input of the virtual MIDI port and control reason as so?!

Comment: Are you on Mac or PC?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to automate reason perimeters through Ableton Live. I found a really good youtube video on this topic:

Hope this helps!
Hiren

Comment: This video is exactly how I arrived at the situation I describe in my question. What I would like to do is control the MIDI parameter *directly*; i.e. not through the use of clips. This is exactly the same question that the guy in this video asks!